# Remove certain null ids using window function

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, function

```
declare @t table(claimid int, name varchar(100), benname varchar(100),amount int, transactionid 
                 int)
insert into @t values( 123, 'John Smith', 'Tom Smith', 500, 1234),
              (123, 'John Smith', NULL, NULL, NULL),
              (322, 'Tom Hanson', 'John Hanson', 1200, 5454),
              (322, 'Tom Hanson', 'Bob Hanson', 1200, 5455),
              (444, 'John Evers', NULL, NULL, NULL)

              select * from @t
```

I'm trying to get the following output from the above dataset:

```
  claimid   name          benname   amount    transactionid
    123    John Smith     Tom Smith  500         1234
    322    Tom Hanson     John Hanson 1200       5454      
    322    Tom Hanson     Bob Hanson  1200       5455
    444    John Evers     NULL        NULL        NULL
```

The idea is to remove records where a claim has multiple records but one has no transaction id, but keep single records that do not have a transaction id.

I've been trying window functions to no avail:

```
  select t.*, row_number() over(partion by claimid, transactionid order by claimid)
  from @t t
```

Thank you!

Comment: You could use max(transactionid) over(partion by claimid), and then filter where either the transactionid is not null OR the maximum of transactionid is null.

Comment: any chance you could show this?

Answer (score 2):

If a claim has no transactions that are not null then by definition the max_transaction is null.

```
select claimid, name, benname, amount, transactionid
from
(select *, 
  max(transactionid) over (partition by claimid) as max_transaction
  from @t) t
where (transactionid is not null) or 
  (max_transaction is null)
```

If a claim has transactions that are not null then max_transaction is not null, and will have no effect.

Comment: Thank you! Never seen that before.